# My bin folder is missing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I looked everywhere for my bin folder (even in the trash) but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I looked at some other answer people said to do but that didn't work either please help me. I am using a mac so maybe someone who might know where my bin folder is at please help. thanks

Comment: I HAVE FIXED YOUR QUESTION SO YOU'RE \*starts to use inside voice\* using your inside voice

Comment: What version of Minecraft do you use?

Comment: What do you need your bin folder for anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The "bin" is now the versions folder if you are using updated minecraft, i believe anything after 1.6. What do you need in the bin folder if you are more descriptive i will try and answer it further

Comment: This has to be the most asked question on mcforum